# Searching information on pages created by views in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-commerce, drupal-search

I'm using Drupal Commerce and creating pages with those products through views.

I would like to be able to search for any of the products and any of their descriptions and have the search results link to those views pages.

I'm currently exploring Search by Page and it's kind of working but it only searches on the page title and doesn't search substrings. I'm downloading and trying everything! Maybe i just need the right combo.

Has anyone dealt with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option "Search: search terms" from filter settings. For this option you have to enable core Search module.

Its searches from Title, Description also we can set "contains" criteria to search any matched data.

Cheers!!!

Comment: but will this give the views pages i created as results?

Comment: For that you can do somthing like this:-
1.Create a view for your search.
2.For Search term override the link and give link for your created views pages. somthing like `search/SEARCH_TERM`